# Linear Programming query

Tags: linear-programming

Rewrite: If $x_1=1$ then $x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=0$ in linear programming if  variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ are binary?

Edit:Sorry the sum of $x_2,x_3,x_4$ and $x_5$ should equal $0$. I tried re-writing it as if the variables are non-binary am not sure of that's how it should be done

Comment: is something missing in your question? Also include your thoughts and attempts if possible. like what do you know, what have you learn, what have you tried, why are you stuck.

Comment: You might be interested in "Formulating Integer Linear Programs: A Rogues' Gallery", by Brown and Dell: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjF6aCj2rbXAhUB5yYKHbHuAjcQFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.nps.edu%2Fdell%2Fdocs%2FBrown_Dell_INFORMS_Transactions_on_Education_January2007.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0IxKOeG6qkFcrOpMIV6Ixl

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

One possible way:

If $y=0$, then we want to force $z=0$ where $y,z \in \{0,1\}$ can be achieved by $y \geq z$ since if $y=0$, we force $z=0$, and if $y=1$, we do not impose any constraint.

Given that information, you might want to solve the original problem using $4$ inequalities.

Note, it can also be solved in a single inequality but it would be great to let you attempt first.